# How can I get item_size in a php var after a sendform checkout in simplecart-js?

Tags: php, javascript, simplecart

I'm a real noob in javascript and I can't find the solution by my own...I would like to get back the size of my items after a sendform checkout in some php variables.

The context:
1 - I'v a product page where customer can choose the size and the quantity and add a product to the basket.
2 - The checkout page, with the thumb, quantity, size price etc and a validation by sendform (I don't have any form on the checkout page, it's just for get all item vars in php)
3 - A page who get back all the items in php,(the customer have to upload a picture for each item):

```
$content = $_POST;

$item_number = array(); // compteur d items
$item = array(); // tableaux qui récupere les valeurs de chaque items

for($i=1; $i < $content['itemCount'] + 1; $i++) 
{
$name = 'item_name_'.$i;
$quantity = 'item_quantity_'.$i;
$price = 'item_price_'.$i;
$thumb = 'item_thumb_'.$i;
$id = 'item_id_'.$i;
$size = 'item_size_'.$i;

$item_number['total'] = $i;

$item[$i]['name'] = $content[$name];
$item[$i]['quantity'] = $content[$quantity];
$item[$i]['price'] = $content[$price];
$item[$i]['thumb'] = $content[$thumb];
$item[$i]['id'] = $content[$id];
$item[$i]['size'] = $content[$size];
}

$total = $item_number['total'];
$line = 0;

while ($line <= $total -1) 
{
$line++;
echo $item[$line]['name'];
    echo $item[$line]['size'];
}?>
```

Everything seems to work fine except for the size...
On the item page I'm juste using a select form for the size with the "item_size" class whose correctly displayed on the checkout page but... nothing on my third page...

Could anyone help me with this pleas...

EDIT: I've found the solution if anyone will wonder this after me:
The custom class attribute that you add to items, in this case

```
class="item_size"
```

is stored in an javascript array called

```
item_options
```

So you must get item_option in a php variable and split the chars chain with an explode function:

```
$content = $_POST;

$item_number = array(); // compteur d items
$item = array(); // tableaux qui récupere les valeurs de chaque items

for($i=1; $i < $content['itemCount'] + 1; $i++) 
{
  //I passed two params in item_options, the size and a path to an picture
  $options = 'item_options_'.$i; //let s get the name of the java var in a php var

  $item_number['total'] = $i; //let s count the number of items

  $item[$i]['options'] = $content[$options]; //let s get the values of item_options
}

$total = $item_number['total'];
$line = 0;

while ($line <= $total -1) 
{
$line++;
$split_options = explode(",", $item[$line]['options']); // explode the chain in few chains                                                  
$split_thumb = explode(":", $split_options[0]); // for each chain, cut the useless part before ":", for exemple thumbPath: ../pictures                                           
$split_size = explode(":", $split_options[1]);

echo $split_thumb[1]; // display the path of my thumb
echo $split_size[1]; // display the size of my item
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the item 
`data["item_size_" + counter] = item.get("size");`
 to the file simplecart.js in SendForm function